# retrieve most recently executed SQL command (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, system-stored-procedures

One of my developers working on a trigger-based logging facility in SQL Server 2008 asked me if there was a command to retrieve the *most recently executed SQL command* within T-SQL.  I thought there was a system stored procedure for just such a function, but it's possible I'm thinking of another product from a prior decade... online searches yielded us no results.

Does anyone have information on anything of the sort?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

sure try this :

```
SELECT
DMExQryStats.last_execution_time AS [Executed At],
DMExSQLTxt.text AS [Query]
FROM
sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS DMExQryStats
CROSS APPLY
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(DMExQryStats.sql_handle) AS DMExSQLTxt
ORDER BY
DMExQryStats.last_execution_time DESC
```

it will returns recently executed queries along with the date and time at which they were executed

Comment: Didn't know that. That's sweet!

Comment: +1 What a beautiful gem! Exactly what I needed for a debugging trigger on some of my tables

Answer (score 4):

Well, the procedure that retrieves the most current SQL batch can safely return itself :)

On a serious note, you can look at [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) and [`sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx) to see when a plan was last time executed, based on the `last_execution_time` column. But note that the method **is not reliable** because it does not account for plans that were evicted from the cache after execution.

Answer (score 1):

What does "most recent" mean in the context of a multi-core machine?

Also, does he mean the most recently started, or the most recently finished?

Finally, he should just open SSMS and look at Activity Monitor.

Comment: in the context we're after it would be 'most recently started'

Comment: the SSMS will surely be useful at allowing us to review the commands, but what we're really seeking is a programmatic solution, hence the specific quest for a system-stored-procedure.